# substring in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

the following substring doesnt work in big query:

substring(note.summary, charindex('[', note.summary)+1, charindex(']', note.summary) - charindex('[', note.summary) -1) as alpha ,

with the error function not found: charindex
Would you be able to help me out? I'm so confused

Comment: If you just need to get rid of square brackets, you can try this: **SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(note.summary, '[',''), ']', '')**

Comment: Maybe, instead of **CHARINDEX** you need **STRPOS**? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#strpos

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve just by looking at a code that we all know doesn't work. Sample data and expected output would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

you could try ->

select (split(note.summary, '['))[safe_ordinal(1)]

Let me know if this works, also you could check regexp_extract here ->

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions?hl=es_419